# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(a^n + b^n+c^n) ^{(1/n)} = \max \{a,b,c\}$, for $a, b, c > 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(a^{n} + b^{n} +c^{n}\right)^{1/n} =  \max\left\{a,b,c\right\}$ for $\displaystyle a, b, c > 0$.

Comment: as $p$ increases, $l^p$ norm converges to $l^\infty$ norm :)

Comment: could you show as what you tried...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estimate:
$$
\max\{a^n,b^n,c^n\}\leq a^n+b^n+c^n\leq 3\max\{a^n,b^n,c^n\}
$$
and so taking $n$-th root,
$$
\max\{a,b,c\}\leq (a^n+b^n+c^n)^{1/n}\leq 3^{1/n}\max\{a,b,c\}
$$
and squeeze.